# Gradle version 1.8 required; install; Gradle version 1.9 required; install; repeat

Tags: android, gradle

updated Studio to 0.4.0

Building yields "Gradle Version 1.8 required" ; set settings to 1.8 bin directory;
build
"Gradle 1.9 required"; set settings to 1.9 bin;
build
"Gradle 1.8 required"

ugh.  no idea what to do, researching...

Comment: UPDATE 4.10pm: rolling back to Studio 0.3.2 still seeing this issue...

UPDATE : trouble may be in compiling in Facebook library, changed build.gradle in facebook library from :

`buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.+'
    }
}` to
`
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}`

Comment: UPDATE : trouble may be in compiling in Facebook library, changed build.gradle in facebook library from : buildscript { repositories { mavenCentral() } dependencies { classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.+' } } to ` buildscript { repositories { mavenCentral() } dependencies { classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+' } }`

Comment: UPDATE: now getting  Compile Error: Execution failed for task ':Hero1:processDebugManifest'
>Manifest merging failed. see console for more info

Comment: UPDATE:  keep getting this error, even after changing all the AndroidManifest.xml files 

Gradle: [AndroidManifest.xml:3, AndroidManifest.xml:3] Main manifest has <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion='7'> but library uses minSdkVersion='8'

where to change minSdkVersion so this doesn't happen?

Comment: UPDATE: (ANSWER)  libraries>fcebook>build.gradle has a specifyer for minSdkVersion.  I set that to 7 and it all compiles.
`defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }`

Answer (score 1):

I have a problem with Gradle in the same way, but I could solve with the instructions on the page where you publish updates Android Studio. I hope it works for you.

http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio040released